# What's the difference between `lsof -p <pid> | wc -l` and `ls /proc/<pid>/fd | wc -l`?

Tags: ulimit, lsof, linux

**Background:** I'm playing around with monitoring the ulimit for running processes for a particular user. (I had occasionally seen processes that were getting started with an incorrect limit.) I asked a couple self-professed Linux gurus, and one suggested `lsof -p <pid>`, while the other suggested `ls /proc/<pid>/fd`, but neither was positive about which more accurately reflects the actual count towards the max open files limit for a process.

So, which is it?

```
lsof -p <pid> | wc -l
```

Or

```
ls /proc/<pid>/fd | wc -l
```

Please elaborate on the difference. Thanks!

Comment: Sounds like homework.

Comment: Not homework. Added better explanation. I had read the `lsof` man pages, and while I suspected the answer was memory-mapped files, I wanted a more experienced person's confirmation.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`lsof` will also give you memory mapped .so-files - which technically isn't the same as a file handle the application has control over. `/proc/<pid>/fd` is the measuring point for open file descriptors - however: Mentioned in the proc-man page - if the main thread of a multithreaded program has terminated, this directory will be unavailable.

`lsof -p <pid>  | grep -v mem | egrep -v '^COMMAND    PID' | wc -l` will show you the same items as `ls /proc/<pid>/fd | wc -l`.

The memory maps is available in `/proc/<pid>/maps`.

Comment: The `lsof` gives you almost the same output, but it also includes `cwd`, `rtd` and `txt` file descriptors.

Comment: Also note that the number of spaces between `COMMAND` and `PID` may vary.  Replace the spaces with `[[:space:]]*` to make it more general.

Comment: I also found `lsof -a -p <pid> -d ^mem -d ^cwd -d ^rtd -d ^txt -d ^DEL | wc -l` [here](https://access.redhat.com/solutions/1210583), while the `lsof` in Android shell (`adb shell`) doesn't support `-a` and `-d`. So I use Kvisle's version finally.